# FORCE_SSL_ADMIN affecting subdomains

Tags: security, ssl

I have a Wordpress installation in the root directory of my host. It includes an SSL certificate for that primary domain (e.g. `domain.com`; not a wildcard certificate).

When I include `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in wp-config.php, suddenly all subdomains also try to redirect to https, despite the fact that there is no SSL certificate for those subdomains.

Some of the subdomains are also Wordpress installs in subfolders of my host (e.g. `test.domain.com`), but others are hosted on completely separate hosts.

When I look at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` I see:

```
static_sts_domain: 
static_upgrade_mode: UNKNOWN
static_sts_include_subdomains: 
static_sts_observed: 
static_pkp_domain: 
static_pkp_include_subdomains: 
static_pkp_observed: 
static_spki_hashes: 
dynamic_sts_domain: domain.com
dynamic_upgrade_mode: STRICT
dynamic_sts_include_subdomains: true
dynamic_sts_observed: 1477318558.379693
dynamic_pkp_domain: 
dynamic_pkp_include_subdomains: 
dynamic_pkp_observed: 
dynamic_spki_hashes:
```

Why would FORCE_SSL_ADMIN affect `dynamic_sts_include_subdomains`? Is there any way around this, while still keeping adequate security in my WP Admin?

Comment: I have a feeling your problem is due to something else.  Try commenting out the FORCE_SSL_ADMIN in wp-config.php... then see if your subdomains are redirecting to https.  IMO, you have another configuration somewhere that is forcing the subdomains to https.

Comment: Removing/Commenting out FORCE_SSL_ADMIN fixes the issue. I took it out, and haven't had any problems since. But I still don't understand _why_ that would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the shared server I have at Network Solutions is forcing HSTS through their service. And since it's a shared hosting server, they refuse to change it.

The solution: I purchased a Wildcard certificate, and installed it on multiple servers for each subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're using [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) which means all your domains share the same `wp-config.php`.

If this is the case, you can limit SSL to only that one domain by wrapping an `if` statement around the `define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true )`.

**NOTE:** Make sure to change the `domain.com` to whatever your true SSL website domain name is.

```
if ( 'domain.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
  define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a multisite, but it does seem like the wp-config is affecting more than just the primary domain.

Comment: I tried that, but it continues to affect subdomains. I'm not using a multisite, and not all of the subdomains are even Wordpress sites. One is a pretty basic PHP site and the other has the open-source [ResourceSpace](http://www.resourcespace.com/) installed. ResourceSpace is even hosted on a completely different host with a CNAME DNS record pointing to it.

Comment: Okay, if it's affecting sites hosted on totally different servers, the issue is not what I thought it was. It sounds more like a DNS or server configuration issue. Hard to help you further without looking at those configs. :-( I'd contact your host provider or whomever you purchased the SSL cert from.

Comment: ddownvoted as this is a great way to get your user hacked in a MS enviroment. It is cool (but not very smart) if you decide to keep the site on HTTP, but never do half a job with SSL, as there is no such thing as partially secure

Comment: ,,, actually it will also break your ability to login once for all the sites in the network

Comment: It answers the OP's question. Not everyone with a network of sites wants to use HTTPS nor buy an SSL cert for each and every one of them. "get your user hacked"? How?